# Invalid default value for 'deposit_date'Invalid default value for 'date'Invalid default value for 'date'Invalid default

Tags: php, database, singlestore

Invalid default value for 'deposit_date'Invalid default value for 'date'Invalid default value for 'date'Invalid default value for 'date'Invalid default value for 'last_access_time'Invalid default value for 'date'Table 'greenhos_newdata.hm2_users' doesn't existTable 'greenhos_newdata.hm2_deposits' doesn't existTable 'greenhos_newdata.hm2_history' doesn't existTable 'greenhos_newdata.hm2_users' doesn't existTable 'greenhos_newdata.hm2_users' doesn't exist

Mebe php  software File Missing  evry one find out please missing software 
iam  tested 2server one  server work fine

Bug  Server  http://demo.greenhostbd.net/phpinfo.php

work fine Server  https://paid-hourly.com/phpinfo.php

How to solv this please help me

Comment: we need to see the code that generated the errors and the database schema

Comment: Welcome in Stackoverflow. We’d love to help you. 
To get a good Answer for your Question: Can you edit the question and provide 
some code and/or more explanations, if there is, of what 
you are doing, and what's wrong. To avoid downvote and bad comments, 
please take some time to read [Help](https://stackoverflow.com/help)
 and [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: your edit does not help, still need to see the actual code

Comment: you can provide me your mail addres please